# PhilJay MPAndroidChart Line Graph Displayed Wrong

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mpandroidchart, linegraph

**Summary**

The graph does not match with the target.

[image]

**Expected Behavior**

The data displayed should be reflected correctly by the graph.

Device (please complete the following information):

Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab A 2016
Android Version 5.1.1
Library Version v3.0.3

**Additional Context**

As you can notice to the image I give correct value to LineDataSet.

[image]

**initLineChart**

[image]

**configXAxis**

[image]

**configYAxis**

[image]

**generateChartData**

[image]

Comment: show your code..

Comment: @Gayathri done.

Comment: give margin and padding for the chart